# How to change the area of an image in a UIAxis in a MATLAB GUI?

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface

I'm making a GUI in MATLAB and part of this application is to display the image using `imshow` (to `UIAxes` area). When I show that picture, I can't size it to match the full available area in this UIAxes.

Is there a way that would spread my picture across the whole UIAxes area?

[image: image from application]